# How to Parse SPCI output from a Keithley SourceMeter 2400?

Tags: python, pyserial

The current value is 02.9967mA and this is what my computer is giving me from the SourceMeter: b'565E-05,+9'. How do I convert this to the proper, displayed current value??? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using [pymeasure's](https://pymeasure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instruments/keithley/keithley2400.html#keithley-2400-sourcemeter) current [property](https://pymeasure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instruments/keithley/keithley2400.html#pymeasure.instruments.keithley.Keithley2400.current)?

If not, please add current code. Your question is extremely limited in the information it provides...

Answer (score 0):

The output is bite type so you have to decode it using .decode().
e.g., serial.read_until('\r').decode()